# Excluir menu de uma lista e mostrar em outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Fala pessoal,sou estagiário,desenvolvo prototipos e sou um iniciante em frotEnd,recentemente a equipe pediu para que eu fizesse um menu que tivesse a possibilidade de arrastar o menu e também excluir o menu para 'comodidade do cliente.
[image: Menus]

Para excluir o menu linkei o x com um id 'toggle' da biblioteca Jquery,mas pediram para que quando eu excluísse esse menu.Ele pudesse aparecer em outro menu 'Menus Ocultos' para que o cliente veja quais menus foram excluidos,e também quando quisesse voltar o menu para lista também fosse possivel.

[image: Menus Ocultos]

Como eu poderia fazer essa façanha alguem pode me ajudar ? 
Obrigado,abraços.

Comment: Ola, Como e que é construido o menu?

Comment: Precisamos de código. Na verdade podemos te ajudar mais com código do que com prints. Seria ótimo vermos sua lógica para podermos dizer no que está errando.